# Is there a way to get Gmail Forward to stop using the wrong date on delayed messages?

Tags: gmail

Gmail's Forward command creates a bogus Date: field having the received date, rather than copy the real Date: field.

Incredible but true. So it can seriously misrepresent a delayed message.

Unlikely I know, but anyone know a remedy?

STEPS:

1 Select a delayed message (one that was received significantly later than sent due to e.g. transmission delay or resending)

2 Record the received date - the date showing in message list:

[image]

and message:

[image]

3 Record the sent date - the date shown on Print:

[image]

and Show Original:

[image]

4 Execute the Forward command (to create a new message containing the major headers and body of the above message).

Expected: Compose window containing Date: being the ***sent*** date.

Observed: Compose window containing Date: being ***received*** date:

[image]

despite that this date is absent from the message being forwarded.

Comment: Your question would benefit from additional detail.  How are you confirming this behavior?  Do you have an example/sample such as the headers from a forwarded email (gold standard) that you can show and point to the inconsistency?

Comment: I can't see what additional detail is needed, but for the benefit of anyone e.g. aware of these two distinct dates, I have added steps to reproduce. Thanks.

Comment: Provide orig. msg headers, not screenshots.  Post the header text in blockquote.  This is done  using a button in the editor, or, precede and follow each header block with a line containing only 3 backquotes (```). Change strings for privacy (recommended) but please do not simply delete/omit content or re-use the same replacement string to mask original strings that are not also identical.  You can do this quickly using find/replace in a text editor.  Happy to look into this further with this info.  How to retrieve headers: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436

Comment: In case it's not clear the headers from 2 messages. Msg #1 was referenced in your post at Step 3: ">> and Show Original" and Msg #2 as referenced in your post at Step 4: ">> Observed"

Comment: You've lost me there. But I did have a redundant screenshot fragment at end of Observed - now removed. Thanks.

Comment: "Provide orig. msg headers, not screenshots." Er, what matters her is what appears to the user - on the screen. This issues is not sensitive to anything in the headers alone. Hence screenshots are what I intend.

Comment: What you put in is what you get out.

Comment: "What you put in is what you get out." I rather thought here the idea was Q in, A out.

Comment: With respect, I've helped you before.  I've indicated, and clarified, the information I want to assist you further.  When you are looking into someone else's problem, and they posted complete message headers in text form thinking that is all anyone will need, you are well within your rights to ask them to also post the information as images, if that is what you find useful to assist.  Whether they do and how you proceed is entirely up to you.

Comment: "With respect, I've helped you before." Indeed and thanks again "the information I want to assist you further."  What suggests headers will help?

Comment: Headers are what "is" in the message.  Knowing 1) what "is", 2) what "is not" and 3) what "appears to be" underpins your ability to properly identify the problem space and determine the next steps.  Mail clients can choose if and what to retrieve.  Gmail takes liberties in this department to "improve" the user experience.  e. g. see part of this answer how Gmail changes names when rendering  senders/recipients from headers: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/166651/197518

Comment: The problem space is already identified. Any delayed message will show you the problem.

Comment: I don't disagree.  I'll leave it at that pending the possibility that you provide information requested of you.